# AngularJs directive to append and remove DOM element with function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm trying to create a `directive` to append a new `html element` to the `DOM` and also to remove it.

The logic to append and remove is already working, except to remove the `element` when clicking on a button. Right now I'm only able to remove it when pressing the `esc` key. I have this directive here:

```
function scLight() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, element) {
            var myEl = '<div sc-light id="lightBox" class="debugModal"><h1>Tests</h1><button ng-click="removeEl()">Close</button></div>',
                ngEl = angular.element(myEl);

            scope.insertEl = function() {
                // angular.element(document.body).append(ngEl); //Append to body
                element.append(ngEl); //Append to element
            }

            scope.removeEl = function() {
                var lightBoxEl = document.getElementById("lightBox"),
                    ngLightBoxEl = angular.element(lightBoxEl);
                ngLightBoxEl.remove();
            }

            document.addEventListener("keyup", function(event) {
                if(event.which == 27) {
                    return scope.removeEl();
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

If I click the button to insert the new `element`, it works. If I press `esc` the `element` is removed. But if I press the button to Close the element, which has this `"ng-click="removeEl()"`, nothing happens.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: You don't need `document.getElementById("lightBox")`.  You should be using `element.find('#lightBox')` since it's inside the directive element.  Also, do you have a " in front of ng-click?  Because if you do, that's the problem.

Comment: ... or even better: `scope.removeEl = function() { ngEl.remove(); }` is enough.

Comment: @ChrisStanley About the ngClick no, it was a typo mistake here. Aboute the getElementById I was using it because I was appending to the body, but forgot about it. Thanks to remind me.

Comment: @ChrisStanley @dfsq Actually, none of them is working. `ngEl.remove()` returns this error: `Referencing DOM nodes in Angular expressions is disallowed!` and the `element.find` is returning an empty object.

Comment: That's really strange.  I guess without the html I wouldn't be able to figure it out.  Sorry!

Comment: @ChrisStanley I've made a plunkr here: https://plnkr.co/edit/WLrnni?p=preview But keep in mind, the main problem is already solved, this is just to simplify the code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You never compiled HTML element, so ng-click attribute doesn't mean anything for Angular.

You should do this:

```javascript
scope.insertEl = function() {
  element.append(ngEl);
  $compile(ngEl)(scope);
}
```

For this, remember to inject `$compile` into directive:

```
function scLight($compile) { /* ... */ }
```

Comment: Well, it worked. But if I try to open it again, it doesn't work. Do you know why?

Comment: How do you try to open it?

Comment: Nevermin, It's because I hade the directive set also on the template. I removed it from there and now it works. Perfect! What is the real job of the $compile here? Do you mind explaining it so I can learn more about this?

Comment: [$compile](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile) service creates linking function from HTML, then this linking function is connected to scope object. Simply saying, ng-click doesn't mean anything until Angular parses template and applies ngClick directive (executes it, invokes). Then ngClick sets up onclick event.